# Using ADB shell in C++ program

Tags: android, c++, linux, shell, adb

I'm am working on a project that requires me to make adb shell commands. The code below is just a test program so that I can understand how to pass adb  shell commands from C++. When I run this code I get the following error: 
sh: adb: command not found. I have the android sdk tools and platform tools in my path and I can run adb shell from my terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


   system("adb devices");



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system` is looking for the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jiang YD I was able to solve it. I just called adb from it's absolute path and it worked.

Comment: It is custom on StackExchange to ask the author of the helpful comment to submit their comment as an answer and then accept their answer.

Comment: What is your new code?